# Parameter Fields Type String Length in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a string parameter in Crystal Report named `invoice_code`
This parameter used in select expert with `IN` formula

```
{invoice_header.invoice_code} in {?invoice_code}
```

This select expert working well until `invoice_code` parameter limited to 254 characters. (delimited by comma)

It's limited by GUI which popping up when you open the report. I've tried to find another type but seems there is no string parameter that can pass more than 254 characters.

How I might solve this problem? I'm using Crystal Report 8.5

Comment: Have you checked constraint is at database side or crystal report

Comment: @siva : I don't get it. What realtion between database contraint and crystal report parameter limmit?